# iOS - UILabel in UITableViewCell erroneously truncates text

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uilabel, truncate

I have a weird issue:

I'm using a `UIPickerView` to pick some values. When a value is picked I want to update a row in a `UITableView` with that value from the pickerview. So I have saved a reference to the particular cell.

So when I select a row in the pickerview I do this in the pickerview delegate method `- didSelectRow...`

```
self.pickerviewCell.textLabel.text = [self.pickerViewDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
```

And then I dismiss the pickerview with an animation. But for some reason after the pickerview is off the screen I see the label in the row being updated with three dots `...` which would indicate that the text is too long for the label and then a second after the dots disappears and the full text of the label is displayed. The text strings are not too long, they are between 3 and 5 characters long and should fit perfectly in the textLabel of a `UITableViewCell`.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Did you try NSLogging the length of the string just after the `self.pickerviewCell.textLabel.text = [self.pickerViewDataSource objectAtIndex:row];`? I'm guessing you probably have to do `[[self.pickerViewDataSource objectAtIndex:row] stringValue];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after some trial and error.

Turned out that since the cell was a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` I needed to reference the instance variable to that custom subclass and not the `UITableViewCell` superclass.

So all I did was go from:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableViewCell *cell`

to

`@property (nonatomic, strong) MyCell *cell`

And it worked out flawlessly. Pretty weird behaviour though. But it works.

**EDIT:**

Actually I was too quick there. It didn't work by just changing the class to my subclass. What I instead noticed worked was that if after setting the `self.pickerviewCell.textLabel.text` property I call `[self.pickerviewCell.textLabel sizeToFit]` But what is weird is that in another View Controller in my application I can do the above **without** needing to call `- sizeToFit` on the `UILabel` for it to display properly.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that my strings ended with `\n`. That worked with `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, but when changing to `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`, the strings were truncated (no matter how long the string was, the three last characters where changed to `...`). Removing `\n` from the strings fixed it.